# c# WPF DataGrid пропадают разделители для типа double

Tags: c#

В общем есть приложение написанное на C# WPF.
Приложение отображает информацию в data grid.
В Data grid есть столбец в котором отображаются данные с типом double.
И по какой-то причине на итальянской локализации Windows 10 в приложении пропадают разделители в типе double.
и возникают проблемы при фильтрации по этим столбцам и при других манипуляциях с этим столбцом.

на итальянской локализации:

[image: на итальянской локализации]

Винда здорового человека:

[image: Винда здорового человека]

Картинки не очень, но смысл понятен.

.Net framework 4.8
в приложении используется стандартный datagrid
в App.xaml.cs
есть такие строки:

```
        var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(culture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

при тестировании все работает хорошо. на Windows с кириллицей в качестве разделителей отображаются запятые, даты в 24-формате.
на Windows c английской локализацией разделители точки, а время pm/am.

на виртулке воспроизвести проблему не смог.
В Италии пользователи не особо продвинутые поэтому проблематично что-то от них ждать.
Из-за чего такое может случиться? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Скорее всего это как-то связано с тем что точка/другие разделители в какой-то локали интерпретируется как разделитель тысяч и всего подобного, а не дробной части, т.е. `1.000 = 1000`.

Comment: У итальянцев запятая как разделитель десятичной части, по идее, а точка - группировка разрядов `1.000.000,00`. Можно чекнуть в `CurrentCulture.NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator`, какой там разделитель, если пустой, можно выполнить фолбэк например в `InvariantCulture`. Возможно у юзера криво настроены правила локализации чисел в операционке.

Comment: Добавил в один из методов проверку на разделитель с выводом в лог. Посмотрим что получится

Comment: @aepot CurrentCulture.NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator возвращает запятую

Comment: Это `DataGridTextBoxColumn`? Запятой нет только при отображении или при редактировании? Или и там и там? Почитайте [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21603693/12888024). Вы отображаете сразу число или предварительно преобразуете в строку? Есть ли `StringFormat`?